# Accessing .Net KeyValuePairs by Key from Powershell Core/7

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.2

What is the best way to access KeyValuePairs from .Net classes in Powershell **(core/7)**?
I have found that the classes I'm trying to use will not let me access the value using the key name  in the indexer.

My current theory is that its due to the underlying .net classes making use of Extension methods which Powershell cannot resolve (but I could be on the wrong path with that...).

Here is an example object:

```
$HTTPMsg = [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]::new()
$HTTPMsg.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=C:\xxx")
$HTTPMsg.Headers.Add("Date", "Wed, 02 Mar 2022 09:41:36 GMT")


$HTTPMsg.Headers

***Output:
Key              Value
---              -----
WWW-Authenticate {Basic realm=C:\xxx}
Date             {Wed, 02 Mar 2022 09:41:36 GMT}
```

Ideally, I would have liked to be able to access the Date value with:

```
$MyDate = $HTTPMsg.Headers["Date"]
```

But this returns $null.

So far the best way I've found is as follows, but this looks way harder than it should be:

```
$MyDate = $HTTPMsg.Headers.Value[$HTTPMsg.Headers.Key.IndexOf("Date")]
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$HTTPMsg.Headers.GetValues("Date")`. Unfortunately the headers are not a simple lookup object and they don't provide an indexer. This is true even in C#, by the way -- being an `IEnumerable` you do get a lot of LINQ extension methods, but those don't allow direct indexing either.

Comment: Thank you - much neater than what i could find!

Comment: It's also worth noting that it exposes the entries via a number of preset properties, so `$HTTPMsg.Headers.Date` should give you the correct value already.

Comment: Thank you - also good option! 
Out of interest how did you find that? Tab complete?

$HTTPMsg.Headers | Get-member

... doesn't show.Date - presumably because it's inherited?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
function Get-HttpHeadersKeyValue {
    param (        
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders]$HttpHeaders,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Key
    )
    $Return = $null
    foreach ($HTTPHeader in $HttpHeaders) {
        if ($HttpHeader.Key -eq $Key) {
            $Return = [string]$HttpHeader.Value
        }
    }    
    return $Return
}

$HTTPMsg = [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]::new()
$HTTPMsg.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=C:\xxx")
$HTTPMsg.Headers.Add("Date", "Wed, 02 Mar 2022 09:41:36 GMT")

$DateString = Get-HttpHeadersKeyValue $HTTPMsg.Headers 'Date'
$DateString
$DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($DateString, 'R', $null)
$DateTime
```

Output:

```
Wed, 02 Mar 2022 09:41:36 GMT

Wednesday, March 2, 2022 9:41:36 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jeroen Mostert answered in the comments:

$HTTPMsg.Headers.GetValues("Date")